# How use implicit conversion to be able to use a typeclass pattern of different type

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, typeclass

There is a good way to make the line `1.print` works without defining an implicit `intPrintable`?

I would like to say to the compiler to use the `stringPrintable` implementation also for `Int` type without provide a new `implicit Printable[Int]`, the idea is to say to compiler that `Int` can be viewed as `String`

Here the example:

```
trait Printable[T]{
  def print(in: T): String
}
object Printable{
  def apply[T](f: T => String): Printable[T] = new Printable[T] {
    def print(in: T): String = f(in)
  }
}
implicit class PrintableOps[T](v: T)(implicit printable: Printable[T]) {
  def print: String = printable.print(v)
}
implicit val stringPrintable: Printable[String] = Printable((in: String) => s"print $in")
implicit def intToString(i: Int): String = i.toString

// doesn't works
1.print

// works
stringPrintable.print(1)

// works
intToString(1).print
```

Comment: Scala will only apply a single implicit conversion when looking for methods.  It will convert the Int(1) to a String, but will not find the String to PrintableOps.   The only way around that is to add additional implicit parameters to your implicit conversion method, which violates the type class pattern, or else declare an explicit IntPrintable type class

Answer (score 0):

Your code is requiring the additional implicit, because it is required as a constructor for your (implicit class) `PrintableOps`

You can simplify this by simply declaring implicit classes more directly:

```
trait Printable[T] {
  def print: String
}

implicit class GenericPrintable[T](in: T) extends Printable[T] {
  def print:String = in.toString
}

implicit class StringPrintable(in:String) extends Printable[String]{
  override def print:String = s"print ${in}"
}

println(  1.print )
println( "1".print )
```

Comment: It sounds like the author wants to use type classes, though, with the conversion (if available) only being invoked when no instances are present.

Comment: We can get the same behaviour adding a generic implicit like this:

`implicit def genericPrintable[T]: Printable[T] = Printable((in: T) => s"print $in")`

But I want to use the String implementation for Int type, not provide a generic implementation

Answer (score 0):

Your `stringPrintable` would require to use `intToString` to convert Int to String.

```
implicit val stringPrintable: Printable[String] = Printable((in: String) => s"print $in")
implicit def intToString(i: Int): String = i.toString
```

Printable.apply() requires an anonymous function and **an anonymous function can't take an implicit value** where  intToString is implicit.

A better workaround is to statically define an implicit Printable[Int] or reform the Printable to GenericPrintable[T] with reference to @Jon Anderson

Answer (score 0):

We need to provide an implicit conversion from `Printer[String] => Printer[Int]` given an implicit conversion from `Int => String`. We can put this on `Printer` companion object:

```
implicit def apply[T0, T1](implicit pin: Printable[T0], c: T1 => T0): Printable[T1] = new Printable[T1] {
    def print(in: T1): String = pin.print(c(in))
}
```

Here the solution:

```
trait Printable[T]{
  def print(in: T): String
}
object Printable{
  def apply[T](f: T => String): Printable[T] = new Printable[T] {
    def print(in: T): String = f(in)
  }
  implicit def apply[T0, T1](implicit pin: Printable[T0], c: T1 => T0): Printable[T1] = new Printable[T1] {
    def print(in: T1): String = pin.print(c(in))
  }
}
implicit class PrintableOps[T](v: T)(implicit printable: Printable[T]) {
  def print: String = printable.print(v)
}
implicit val stringPrintable: Printable[String] = Printable((in: String) => s"print $in")
implicit def intToString(i: Int): String = i.toString

// now working
1.print

// works
stringPrintable.print(1)

// works
intToString(1).print

// don't compile, and it's ok, because no implicit conversion (A => String) is provided
case class A(in: String)
A("A").print
```

What do you think?

Comment: If you add an implicit, `doublePrintable` for instance, this stops working.

Comment: Yep, I can't figure out why